# Does setTimeout() reset itself?

Tags: javascript

I have a flurry of interrupts coming into a handler and I don't want to service them until 5ms have passed since the last interrupt, indicating the flurry is over.

My thought was to call `setTimeout(LookAtInterrupts, 5)` each time the handler is entered, but I don't see in the `setTimeout()` documentation that it will cancel a pending scheduled call if it's called before that execution occurs.

Is that, in fact, what it will do?  I don't want to get called 5ms after every handler interrupt, just the last one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it won't - you can have as many pending timeouts as you want.

The function returns a key that you can use to cancel a timeout later:

```
var key = setTimeout( ... );
```

Then to cancel it later:

```
clearTimeout(key);
```

Calling `clearTimeout()` with an already-expired key is not an error, so you don't have to worry about synchronization problems.

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout` will not reset itself.

You can reset a timeout manually by

```
var timeout = setTimeout(...);
clearTimeout(timeout);
```

Answer (score 1):

A `setTimeout()` won't cancel any previous timeouts implicitly.

However, you can achieve that by storing the identifier in a variable and clearing that each time.

```
var timeoutId = null;
var yourFn = function() { 
     clearTimeout(timeoutId);
     timeoutId = setTimeout(fn, 5);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store a reference. `setTimeout` result can be stored and cleared later on.

For a "resettable" `setTimeout`:

```
// first assign it
var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
  foo();
}, 50);

// then look for an existing assignment before re-assinging
if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
timeout = setTimeout(function(){
  bar();
}, 50);
```

References:

- [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)
- [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearTimeout)

As an aside, [be careful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647215/what-is-minimum-millisecond-value-of-settimeout) when setting a timeout < 5ms. Though HTML5 is supposed to support 4, I doubt you're actually getting anywhere close to that (w/ cost of spinning up the timeout).

Answer (score 0):

Store reference to that setTimeout call in a variable, and after each successfull interrupt, before creating timeout, cancel the previous timeout,

```
var tv = null;

function interrupt(){
    if(tv !== null){
        clearTimeout(tv);
    }
    tv = setTimeout(LookAtInterrupts,5)
}

function LookAtInterrupts(){

}
```

By this, you'll guarantee that only the last interrupt will continue execution in 5ms intervals. I hope that was clear.

Answer (score 0):

While you can implement this yourself, a more practical solution would be to grab underscore.js and use it's debounce function (see http://underscorejs.org/#debounce).

Then you can do:

```
var lookAtInterrupts = _.debounce(handleInterrupt, 5);
```

the resulting function will only run at most once every 5 ms.

Answer (score 0):

When `setTimeout()` is executed it schedules one call to your binded `function()`.

If you want to cancel it you have to get ID returned by `setTimeout()` and clear as:

```
var timeOutID = setTimeout( LookAtInterrupts, 5 );
(...)
clearTimeOut( timeOutID );
```