# setTimeout - Weird behavior

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Consider the following HTML:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" onblur="window.setTimeout('document.title += 2;', 0);" />
        <input type="button" onclick="document.title += 1" />
    </body>
</html>
```

[[Demo with 0 delay](http://jsfiddle.net/2x4wg/), [100ms delay](http://jsfiddle.net/2x4wg/1/), [150ms delay](http://jsfiddle.net/2x4wg/2/)]

And the following steps:

- User enters the input (focus).
- User clicks the button.

Now, the events would occur on the following order:

- Input Text blur event.
- Button click event.

Testing this on all reachable browsers I get:

```
document.title = '21' //Expected behavior
```

But! On production browser (Windows XP + IE 7), I get:

```
document.title = '12' //Unexpected behavior
```

I also tried simulating it in IE 7 mode on my local machine (IE 10), couldn't reproduce it tho.

This is obviously a simplified example of the problem I'm having. Otherwise I could simply get rid of the setTimeout.

In the real scenario, the setTimeout call is actually being made by a third party script library (ASP.NET Dev Express Components).

Apart from the actual solution to this problem (which I think I can handle), what explanation could be applied to this behavior?

**Update:**

Using the expression `new Date().getTime()` to get the time of each step executed by the browser. It happens as follows:

```
1387369361417 //document.title += 1
1387369361433 //document.title += 2
```

Comment: Maybe IE7 triggers the click event before the blur event? *"In that case, the button click event can't happen before the blur function."* How sure are you about this?

Comment: @Felix Kling: Nope, without the setTimeout, it actually evaluates as `document.title ='21'`

Comment: If you don't use the window.setTimeOut function and you write `onblur="document.title += 2;"`, what is the output?

Comment: I tested the exact HTML contained in the question with a dummy HTML file at production environment. 100% sure.

Comment: I bet this is because with setTimeout set to 0, the browser is returning idle at an unexpected time.

Comment: @ProGM: Output is `document.title ='21'`

Comment: With a timeout of 10 instead of 0, the output is the same.

Comment: @jibsales: That was my theory.  There's no guarantee when the function inside `setTimeout` will run.  Even with `0` ms.  `setTimeout('', 0)` actually puts the function at the bottom of the call stack, to be executed ASAP (ie whenever the browser feels like being idle).

Comment: Every browser has a minimum default delay. Maybe it happens that in IE7 the default delay is too long. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout#Minimum.2F_maximum_delay_and_timeout_nesting

Comment: @FelixKling: I think you're right!  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9647221

Comment: But, actually, why you need to set a timeout of 0 millisecs to a code? What is the use case?

Comment: @ProGM: This should explain it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/779379

Comment: @ProGM: As stated in the question, It's not my code, it's about third party components scripts (in this case, ASP.NET DevExpress Components).

Comment: @ProGM Its usually used when the time value is dynamic and you want immediate execution of the function. The confusion happens in that it doesn't actually immediately execute, rather, waits until the browser is idle from other tasks before execution.

Comment: @ProGM In node.js parlance, this is functionally equivalent to `process.nextTick()`

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders: Do you *really* need to support IE7?  Our deepest condolences :(

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat: Sadly, in this case, IE7 is the only browser that has to be supported.

Comment: As a workaround, why not try putting the `onclick` into a `setTimeout` with a timeout *longer* than that of the `onblur`?  Would that work?

Comment: That would cause a lot of rework, as this thing actually impacts a lot of pages. I'll probably have to hook several functions from the third party script and avoid using the `setTimeout` on a certain condition.

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities:

1. Your click (mousedown + mouseup) is finishing before IE7's minimum timeout period.
2. The mousedown status is blocking scripts. Events must wait until other scripts and user-interactions are finished before they fire. And given the history of script-UI weirdness/terribleness in IE, I'd bet the mousedown "begins a user interaction" and the mouesup "ends user interaction". Load this up in IE7:

   ```
   <input type="text" onblur="window.setTimeout('output(2));', 0); output(3);" />
   <input type="button" onclick="output(1);" />
   ```

   http://jsfiddle.net/sMcE3/

   … and after you'd focus()'d on the text field, click that button *real slow-like*. I'm guessing you'll see `312`. (As opposed to the `321` that any half-decent browser will show.)

Comment: If I click it very slow, I'm getting 321. It seems like the blur event would happen before the mouseup. And the click event would execute only after mouseup.

Comment: Ah. That sounds more like possibility #1 then.