# `setTimeout` is set to 1, why is my clock skipping seconds?

Tags: javascript, animation

I am working on a decimal clock (100min₁₀ / hr & 100s₁₀ / min₁₀). [The code](http://codepen.io/dysbulic/pen/LExXNb) is skipping decimal seconds (in Firefox and Chrome in Ubuntu 14 & Android). The delay in `setTimeout` is 1.

```
function updateTime() {
    var now = new Date()
    var h = now.getHours();
    var m = now.getMinutes();
    var s = now.getSeconds();
    document.getElementById('babylonian').innerHTML = h+":"+padDigit(m)+":"+padDigit(s)
    document.getElementById('decimal').innerHTML = h + "h" + padDigit( Math.round( ( 100 * m ) / 60) ) + "." + padDigit( Math.round( ( 100 * s ) / 60 ) )

    setTimeout(updateTime, 1);
}

function padDigit(i) {
    return i<10 ? '0' + i : i
}

updateTime()
```

The clocks seem to be ticking in sync. I don't understand why.

Comment: Do you really need update clock 1000 times in second? its milliseconds.. try to use setTimeout value at least 200

Comment: skipping decimal seconds? Can you explain where it is skipping.

Comment: possible duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647215/what-is-minimum-millisecond-value-of-settimeout

Comment: What do you expect `Math.round()` to do?

Comment: @neo, no, it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @Will, thanks, it should definitely be floor :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because there are 100 "decimal seconds" per minute, but only 60 seconds. So for each second there's 100/60 "decimal seconds".

When you base the computation on `now.getSeconds()` you'll get leaps in the "decimal seconds".

Work with something finer grained as well such as `now.getMilliseconds()`:

```
var s = now.getSeconds() + now.getMilliseconds()/1000;
...
...  ...  ... Math.floor(  s * 100  / 60 )  ...
```

(And do the same for minutes to avoid skipping decimal minutes.)