# setImmediate and browsers other than Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript

I understand that there is some controversy about the name of `setImmediate`. Does anyone know if this useful functionality will make it into V8/Spider Monkey any time soon, regardless of name?

Comment: Isn't it analogous to `setTimeout(funcRef, 0);`? Am I missing something?

Comment: `setTimeout(funcRef, 0);` [clips to 4ms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9647221/2039244). Presumably `setImmediate` would not. [Interesting article on this subject](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2011/09/19/script-yielding-with-setimmediate/).

Comment: If the task runs immediately, what's the sense in returning an ID that can be cancelled? And is 4ms timer resolution really that big of a deal?

Comment: A 1GHz CPU can perform 4 million operations in 4ms (at least). Which may or may not be a big deal depending on your use-case.

Comment: @BenAston The 15.6ms timer resolution seems like it would be a big deal, but 4ms doesn't seem like it would be enough of a difference to noticeably slow the UI. Assuming that at 0ms setImmediate would pause the thread for nanoseconds each time such a task ran, couldn't you just quadruple these operations up? Would you really notice the impact on the UI thread between 4 and 0 ms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/setImmediate:

> Note: This method is not expected to become standard, and is only implemented by recent builds of Internet Explorer and Node.js 0.10+. It meets resistance both from [Gecko](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=686201) (Firefox) and [Webkit](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=146172) (Google/Apple).

Comment: So, that's a no, then? It seems that this is a missing feature in those browsers then. setTimeout has a wait time (4ms?) specified in the standard IIUC. Without setImmediate (or at the very least nextTick) there is no clean way to achieve asynchronous behavior without the 4ms noop.

Comment: No clean way; although there are polyfills for it … check the article @sdgluck mentioned already, http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/07/09/the-case-for-setimmediate/ for some broader information on the topic.