# Why doesn't setTimeout(.., 0) execute immediately?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
     console.log("I'm message from timeout");
},0);

console.log("I'm message from outside timeout");

//1. I'm message from outside timeout
//2. I'm message from timeout
```

Why the inner instructions don't execute first, despite setting setTimeout time on 0? I use various times including 0/null and I'm wondering how to both retain setTimeout object and execute its instructions with the flow.

Comment: setTimeout *always* is deferred until the *next* "execution time" of JavaScript. A value of 0/null does not change this (and is treated as a value of 5 in modern browsers).

Comment: I wrote a long answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32580940/cleartimeout-necessary-after-settimeout-with-0ms/32591948#32591948 and there are likely many other related questions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647215/what-is-minimum-millisecond-value-of-settimeout?lq=1

Comment: You should check this out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Answer (score 7):

Javascript code runs only on one thread. `setTimeout` schedules a function to run later. So in js when all currently running code finish its execution , `event` loop will look for any other event.
So `setTimeout( .. 0)` will make code run after the current loop.

`console.log("I'm message from outside timeout");` will be first scheduled to executued. As soon as it finish the `setTimeout` will be executed

So bottom line `setTimeout(myfunction ,0)` will run myfunction 0ms after currently executing function. & in your case the current execution loop is

```
console.log("I'm message from outside timeout");
```

If you add another  console.log("I'm message from outside timeout1");
so current event loop will first log

```
I'm message from outside timeout
I'm message from outside timeout1
```

before starting  `setTimeout` function.

**NOTE** `setTimeout` has a minimum timeout of 4ms . You can look at this [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341803/difference-between-settimeoutfn-0-and-settimeoutfn-1) to know more about it

Comment: The way you explain the order is confusing. `setTimeout` itself is executed before the `console.log`, only the function passed *to* it is scheduled.

Comment: Regarding "*…minimum timeout of 4ms*", that is not necessarily true. The current [*WHATWG spec*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#timers) says "*… after five such nested timers, however, the interval is forced to be at least four milliseconds*". So the minimum delay is whatever the implementation has it set to.

Comment: Yes, the "4ms minimum" is very misleading. Here's a fiddle to verify: http://jsfiddle.net/pgjbn8o5/