# Why setTimeout function in javascript calls after other line eventhough time is for zero seconds?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, asynchronous, settimeout

I am using setTimeout function:-

```
function myFunction() {
 alert("1"); // Called 1st


setTimeout(function(){ 
     alert("2");  // Called Third
}, 0000);

/*Same as setTimeout window.setTimeout(slowAlert, 0000);function slowAlert() { alert("That was Same as setTimeout!");}*/ 

     alert("39"); // Called Second
}
```

I am unable to understand why alert('2') calls on third time even I am using zero seconds

Comment: Because `setTimeout` is asynchronous function.

Comment: But Time is zero seconds so it won't matter whether setTimeout function is asynchronous because it don't use any second for executing that codes of line

Comment: @VIKASKOHLI it does matter obviously, or you wouldn't have to ask the question :)

Comment: @VIKASKOHLI, _But Time is zero seconds so it won't matter whether setTimeout_ - [see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40904193/2545680). The time specifies when the callback should be added to the event loop, not when the callback will be executed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't setTimeout(.., 0) execute immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36904773/why-doesnt-settimeout-0-execute-immediately)

Answer (score 3):

`setTimeout` adds your callback to the [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop), which will be called later when a browser isn't busy. The second parameter just tells a browser **when** your callback will be **added** to the event loop, not when **execute** it. In your case it's zero, so the callback is added almost immediately (it's actually in about 4 milliseconds) to the loop, but it will be executed later when a browser has time. The other alerts in your code don't use `setTimeout` and so they are executed immediately in current tick, that's why they are executed before the callback.

Comment: It means even we are using zero seconds,  the setTimeout function itself  take some time

Comment: @VIKASKOHLI, I didn't understand what you mean. If you use zero seconds, it means that callback will be added to the the loop immediately, but it will be executed later when a browser has time. You need to understand how the even loop works.

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout()` calls callback function asynchronously.  So there is no guarantee of order even though it is set with zero timeout.

To make it synchronous, remove `setTimeout()` and just call `alert('2');` directly.

```
function myFunction() {
   alert("1"); // Called 1st
   alert("2");  // Called second
   alert("39"); // Called third
}
```

**Update:**

If you want to make sure that the order remain intact then move `alert("39")` also inside `setTimeout()`.

```
function myFunction() {
   alert("1"); // Called 1st
   setTimeout(function() {
       alert("2");  // Called second
       alert("39"); // Called third
   }, 0);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to execute that code on 2nd time using setTimeout Function because I want to run that codes of line on second time if there is no delay

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so, let's work a tick at a time and see what your app is doing :

> Tick 1 - alert("1");   An alert, better display it now!
>
> Tick 2 - setTimeout(function(){ },0000); A timeout with 0seconds? OK, I'll
>   wait
>
> Tick 3 - alert("39");  Another Alert, display!!
>
> Tick 4 - alert("2");    It's been 0 seconds, what was in that timeout again?

Comment: It may be zero or 1 or any other positive value . If it is zero then it will be executed first otherwise not

Answer (score 0):

since JS in browser is single threaded setTimeout creates a new "stack" that gets executed `n` milliseconds after the current stack is cleared, i.e. after the current function finished

Answer (score 0):

Because setTimeout is asynchronous kind of function. Because it breaks the synchronous execution flow. But it does not executed simultaneously like a separate thread.

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
     alert("2");  // Called Third
}, 0000);
```

The above code executed once after all other statements outside of it are finished executing.