# Why is the `setTimeout` callback called after function execution, even if the delay is 0 ms?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, event-loop

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log("m");
}, 0);
console.log("s");
```

Why does this code print `"s"` before `"m"`, even if the `setTimeout` callback is supposed to wait for 0 ms?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't setTimeout(.., 0) execute immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36904773/why-doesnt-settimeout-0-execute-immediately)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a promise, or call an async function, or set a timeout for 0 milliseconds, the function is immediately queued into the [Javascript event loop](https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-event-loop-and-the-rise-of-async-programming-5-ways-to-better-coding-with-2f077c4438b5?gi=22061abafb1e). Essentially, the function is added to a queue of functions to call, and once the javascript interpreter has nothing to do it'll start calling those functions. So, when you set a timeout for 0 milliseconds, it queues the `console.log("m")`, then calls the `console.log("s")`, then it has nothing to do so it finishes the queued `console.log("m")`, which is why it's out of order.

Answer (score 2):

A browser or node.js always run a single threaded event loop to run your code. On the first run it will always run your synchronous code but may also que up asynchronous events that will call back later. Thats why we call the function here `callback function` it will be called later.

`setTimeout` is a microtask.

That means the `function` that you see isnt gona executed immedantly, it is gonna first queued up and will be executed within the next event loop.

Also a sidefact: `0 ms` just means it will minimum wait `0 ms` not exact 0

Answer (score -1):

it just because JS is single-threaded and event loop works that way. 
setTimeout has written in a way that it will send you function or whatever you want to do in a callback queue.
and then move forward to the next line, once next line executed it will not run your setTimeout part, or in other words, it will not process the setTimeout part until the stack is not empty.

so this is your code, and it will execute like this.

```
 setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("m");
 } , 0)
 console.log('s');
```

1. the first line will execute and it will send the inner part of setTimeout to callback queue and move to the 2nd line.
2. while 2nd line is executing the setTimeout part will wait till the stack is not emplty and as soon as 2nd line finishes execution,
3. the setTimeout part will execute,

maybe it's confusing by words, let's see this in action. I bet you can not get a better example than this to understand it, it's explained in [the best way by Philip robert.](http://latentflip.com/loupe/?code=JC5vbignYnV0dG9uJywgJ2NsaWNrJywgZnVuY3Rpb24gb25DbGljaygpIHsKICAgIHNldFRpbWVvdXQoZnVuY3Rpb24gdGltZXIoKSB7CiAgICAgICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coJ1lvdSBjbGlja2VkIHRoZSBidXR0b24hJyk7ICAgIAogICAgfSwgMjAwMCk7Cn0pOwoKY29uc29sZS5sb2coIkhpISIpOwoKc2V0VGltZW91dChmdW5jdGlvbiB0aW1lb3V0KCkgewogICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coIkNsaWNrIHRoZSBidXR0b24hIik7Cn0sIDUwMDApOwoKY29uc29sZS5sb2coIldlbGNvbWUgdG8gbG91cGUuIik7!!!PGJ1dHRvbj5DbGljayBtZSE8L2J1dHRvbj4%3D)

Answer (score -2):

because JS code goes in order one by one. When you specifying setTimeout to 0 is still waiting, in C++ lang this would be something like this 0.000000245ms, and JS runs often on C++/C browser.

try this simple example

```
for (let x = 0; x < 500; x++) {
  setTimeout(() => console.log(x), 0);
}
console.log('hello');
```