# how .then() method actually works in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, promise

i have question about Promises on something that is really confusing me.

The **.then()** method

before i will get into the thing that confusing me about the **.then()** method i would do a brief explanation on how the Javascript Engine works based on my knowledge.

From what i know Javascript is not a asynchronous but rather a synchronous language

The Javascript Engine works synchronously but the Javascript Engine isn't the only thing that run on the Browser

There are things like the Rendering Engine,setTimeout,HTTP Request etc
[image]

And the Javascript Engine can talk to them **when** we are calling a native functions for example
`setTimeout`
so the `setTimeout` function will call a program outside of the Javascript Engine for timing
[image]

And of course when the timer will end it will send the callback to the event queue and only after the Javascript finished all the Executions context only then it will look at the event queue

Alright now let's move to Promises
My question is how `.then()` knows when `resolve()` was called
I have read articles and they say that `.then()` works asynchronously which is sounds weird to me because Javascript is synchronous doesn't it ?
maybe i didn't understood them correctly

so i made my own assumptions on how `.then()` works because i haven't found a source that gave me the feeling and confidence that i know exactly how `.then()` works.

one of them(my assumptions) was that there are two stages in the `.then` method

i will use this code for demonstration to explain my assumption

```
var myPromise = new Promise(function(resolve){
                    resolve('Hello Stackoverflow !');
                 });
                 
                 myPromise.then(function(result){
                    console.log(result);
                 });
```

so based on my assumption the `resolve('Hello Stackoverflow !')` function calls the `.then` method and the
`.then` check two things here are the following

1.if the callback parameter of `.then()` was created

2.if the Promise status is set to resolved

and if both conditions are true then the `.then()` method will insert the callback with the value `Hello Stackoverflow !` to the event queue and only after all the execution context popped of the stack then it will run the callback and we will get the result `Hello Stackoverflow !`

again this is **based only on my assumption** maybe i'm totally wrong about that.

So if you examine what i just said you can reach a conclusion that the `.then` method is called twice
Why ?

the first time is when the resolve function called it but not all conditions were true
the one that isn't true is that the `.then` callback parameter was created but it wasn't created yet
because we haven't got to the line of code that we created the callback so the condition is false

and the second time is when we called the `.then` method and created the callback and all conditions were  now true so it will insert the callback to the event queue and after all the execution contexts will popped of the stack then the callback will be called
and we will get `Hello Stackoverflow !`

hope you understand what i tried to explain

Am i right or wrong ?

Thanks in advance for all of you :)

Comment: The `.then()` method is called immediately after `myPromise` is initialized. The `.then()` method and the *callback* passed to `.then()` are two completely different things.

Comment: Callbacks scheduled using Promises are not added to the task queue - they are [added to the micro-task queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66387109/javascript-async-callbacks-promise-and-settimeout()).

Comment: "*if both conditions are true [it] will insert the callback with the value to the event queue*" - yes. But if the promise is not fulfilled yet, the `then` method just stores the callback in an internal list, so that it can be put in the event queue by the `resolve` call.

Comment: may I suggest reading answer on same topic.

Comment: for some odd reasons we seem to miss the concept of WEB API that is now part of Js engine here is very good article as whats happening behind the scene through web API promise is part of thread pool for web API which makes asynchronous like operative https://dev.to/steelvoltage/if-javascript-is-single-threaded-how-is-it-asynchronous-56gd

Comment: @CaptainMagmelatonCap, you received a few answers. Any feedback?

Answer (score 3):

> you can reach a conclusion that the `.then` method is called twice

This is not true. The `then` method is called just like any method is called: when the statement/expression having that method call is *evaluated* in the normal execution flow.

The order of synchronous execution of your example is as follows:

1. The callback function `function(resolve) {...}` is passed to the `Promise` constructor function.
2. This constructor immediately *executes* the callback it receives as argument, passing it a `resolve` and `reject` argument.
3. `resolve` is called, passing it the string.
4. The promise implementation, that implemented the `resolve` function, is therefore notified and sets the state of the promise object to fulfilled, and registers the value it is fulfilled with (the string).
5. The promise constructor finishes execution and returns the promise instance, which is assigned to `var myPromise`
6. The callback function `function(result) {...}` is passed to the `myPromise.then()` method.
7. The native `then` implementation registers the callback, but does not execute it. As the promise is resolved, this callback is put on the promise job queue.
8. The native `then` function finishes execution and returns a new promise. Your script does not capture this return value, so let's just label this new promise as `promiseB`.
9. The scripts ends, leaving the call stack empty.

Now we get to what is commonly called the *asynchronous* execution part, which always starts with an entry in a job/event queue:

10. The host will check which job queues have entries, giving precedence to job queues that have a high priority. A Promise job queue has a very high priority, typically higher than the event queue that deals with user interaction or other external events. So, the job that was put in the queue at step 7 above, is taken out of the Promise Job queue.
11. The above job executes.
12. If more `then` calls had been made on this promise then also those callback functions that have been registered as `then` callback (such as the one registered in step 7) on the `myPromise` object and have a corresponding entry in the promise job queue. NB: I am ignoring the `async`/`await` syntax here, to keep it simple.
13. So in this case the only `then`-callback in your script is executed -- not to be confused with the `then` method itself (which was already executed in step 6). The `then`-callback is executed with as argument the value that the promise `myPromise` was fulfilled with (the string that was registered in step 4).
14. `console.log` is executed.
15. the `then` callback finishes execution and returns `undefined`.
16. `promiseB` is fulfilled with this return value (`undefined` in this case).
17. The job execution finishes. The call stack is empty again.

Comment: Finally, got it, could you improve your answer with a second example using the async/await syntax?

Comment: @shellwhale, like I wrote on my answer, I didn't want to go there, so to focus on the question asked here. If you have a doubt about `async/await` and can't find an answer on this site, feel free to post, and I will be glad to have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

> so based on my assumption the resolve('Hello Stackoverflow !') function calls the `.then` method and the `.then` check two things here are the following

wrong, the resolve callback doesn't call the `.then` method. you first need to understand how promises work.

while creating a promise object, we provide a execution function to the promise constructor.

```js
const promise = new Promise (
    () => {} // execution function
)
```

the Promise contructor will pass 2 argument (i.e. 2 callback function) to this execution function and invoke it. thus we write 2 parameter (usually named resolve, reject) to use this arguments

```js
const promise = new Promise (
    (resolve, reject) => {} // resolve and reject parameter catches the argument provided to the executor function 
)
```

when Promise constructor invokes this execution function, depending on your logic either resolve or reject will be called (with a single argument). if resolve is called, promise state will be set to fulfiled. else if reject is called, promise state will be set to rejected.

- when this promise is settled (i.e. either fulfiled or rejected), it will add the stored callback functions to the microtask queue

to use/consume the promise, you use methods provided by the promise object, ex: `.then` method. when you use `.then` method, if promise is in pending state, the `.then` method stores the callback in the promise object

```js
promise.then(
    val => console.log(val); // this callback function will be stored in the pending promise object, else if is already settled callback will be added to the microtask queue
)
```

else if promise is already settled, callback function will be added to the microtask queue

**Note:** if you are chaining another `.then` method, it's callback will appended to the new promise object that has been returned by the previous `.then` method

- `.catch` method works same way as `.then` method

Answer (score 0):

A very basic barebone implementation of Promise, which may answer your question:

```
class Promise {
  constructor(fn) {
    this.status = "PENDING";
    this.result = null;
    this.successCB = [];
    this.errorCB = [];
    fn(this.resolve, this.reject); // This actually goes into microtask
  }

  resolve = data => {
    this.status = "SUCCESS";
    this.result = data;
    this.successCB.forEach(eachCB => eachCB(data));
    this.successCB = [];
  };

  reject = error => {
    this.status = "FAILED";
    this.result = error;
    this.errorCB.forEach(eachCB => eachCB(error));
    this.errorCB = [];
  };

  then = (successCB, errorCB) => {
    switch (this.status) {
      case "PENDING":
        this.successCB.push(successCB);
        this.errorCB.push(errorCB);
        break;
      case "SUCCESS":
        successCB(this.result);
        break;
      case "FAILED":
        errorCB(this.result);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };
}
```

To keep it simple I haven't considered chaining promises or advanced error handling. But this should work when `then` is executed before/after resolve was complete.

Comment: the "*`// This actually goes into microtask`*" comment is on the wrong line. It should be on the `forEach`s and on the calls in the settled `case`s.

Comment: The function executes during promise creation, irrespective of  `then`. Hence its delegated to microtask within the contructor.

Comment: No, it's not a microtask, the executor callback is called synchronously from within the constructor. Microtasks are only involved in the handlers passed to `then`.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks !

Comment: This calls the callbacks synchronously. Secondly, it allows the promise state to switch from fulfilled to rejected and vice versa. That is not how it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

We need to differentiate between registering a callback and calling the callback. When you do:

```
/*...*/.then(yourfunction);
```

then you have two functions in question. First, `yourfunction` is a function (the **callback**) that you pass to the `.then()`. And, the `.then()` is also a `function`.

And now is the best moment to clarify that even though Javascript is a synchronous language, it lets you do things asynchronously. Events are being picked up by the event handler.

## Example 1

```js
function handleSuccess(value) {
    console.log(`Success, the result is ${value}`);
}

function handleFailure(reason) {
    console.log(`Failure, the reason is ${reason}`);
}

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(5);
}).then(handleSuccess, handleFailure);

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject("some problem");
}).then(handleSuccess, handleFailure);
```

We see that upon calling `resolve` or `reject`, the corresponding callback is triggered.

## Example 2

```js
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => [resolve, reject][parseInt(Math.random() * 2)](Math.random() * 1000), 1000);
    }).then(handleSuccess, handleFailure);

    function handleSuccess(value) {
        console.log(`Success, the result is ${value}`);
    }

    function handleFailure(reason) {
        console.log(`Failure, the reason is ${reason}`);
    }
```

The example above is working asynchronously. We can see that the success or failure handler is being handled exactly when the promise is either handled or failed.