# NodeJS Promise resolve unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, settimeout, es6-promise

I have the following code, which does not work as I expect.

```js
const bar = () => console.log('bar')
const baz = () => console.log('baz')
const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    resolve('should be right after baz, before bar')
);
const foo = () => {
    console.log('foo')
    setTimeout(bar, 0)
    myPromise.then(resolve => console.log(resolve))
    baz()
}

foo()
console.log('before bar')
```

The result:

```
foo
baz
before bar
should be right after baz, before bar
bar
```

According to what's written in [https://nodejs.dev/](https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-nodejs-event-loop) , promise resolve will happen right after the function.

> Promises that resolve before the current function ends will be executed right after the current function.

So I expect 'should be right after baz, before bar' to happen right after the end of `foo()`, before `console.log('before bar')`.
Can someone explain why it doesn't?

Comment: Promises will never resolve in the same execution frame (by spec). Digging for more details.

Comment: calling `.then()` on a promise (or `await` or putting it in `Promise.all()` etc. interactions) does not "run" the promise. It's not a task that gets "activated". A promise already represents some async operation. It's a notification mechanism for its end status. That's it. With that said, your code does not really make much sense - you *could* make it output things in the way you expect, however, that's useless. You should ***NEVER*** rely on a specific way unrelated async tasks finish.

Comment: "*promise resolve will happen right after the function.*" no, not *after the function*. It happens after the run-to-completion cycle. And the completion here is after `console.log('before bar')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Callbacks passed to `setTimeout` are added in the task queue whereas the callbacks related to promise fulfilment or rejection are added in the micro-task queue.

These queues are only processed *after* the synchronous execution of your script, i.e. the javascript code you wrote.

As a result, `'before bar'` is logged *before* any asynchronous callbacks are invoked.

#### How your code executes?

1. Script execution starts.
2. Function `bar`, `baz`, and `foo` are defined. Promise constructor is also called which leads to the invocation of `resolve` function, resolving the promise synchronously
3. `foo` function is called

   1. `'foo'` is logged on the console
   2. `setTimeout` is called, scheduling `bar` to be called asynchronously. `bar` will be added in the task queue
   3. `then` method is called on `myPromise`, scheduling the fulfilment handler to be invoked asynchronously. This fulfilment handler is added in the micro-task queue
   4. `baz` function is called, logging `'baz'` on the console
4. `foo` function ends. Control return to the next line from where `foo` was called
5. Last `console.log` statement is executed, logging `'before bar'` on the console
6. Script execution ends

At this point, console output is as shown below:

```
foo
baz
before bar
```

and the task queue contains a task to execute the `bar` function whereas the micro-task queue contans a micro-task to execute the fulfilment handler of the `myPromise`.

After the script execution ends, task and micro-task queues can be processed.

The micro-task queue is processed:

- after each callback as long as the call-stack is empty *(this is what nodejs.dev is referring to)*
- after each task

Script execution is a task and after its execution, micro-task queue will be the first one to be processed, logging `'should be right after baz, before bar'` on the console.

At last, the task queue is processed, `baz` function is called, logging `'baz'` on the console.

---

Following might be a helpful read to understand the micro-task and the task queue: [JavaScript async callbacks - Promise and setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66387109/javascript-async-callbacks-promise-and-settimeout)

Answer (score 1):

The MDN documentation for [`Promise.prototype.then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#return_value) states (emphasis is mine):

> Once a Promise is fulfilled or rejected, the respective handler function (onFulfilled or onRejected) will be called ***asynchronously*** (scheduled in the current thread loop).

You might find the snippet below enlightening:

```js
Promise.resolve("I resolved").then((v) => console.log(v));
console.log("hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

If want to understand the asynchronous concept, you should check out this awesome [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&t=634s).

I'll try to explain to you the sequence of how the code is running here

First of all, we are Initializing all the variables with functions.
Then we're calling `foo()`, and later `console.log('before baz')`.

What will happen on calling `foo` is `foo` will enter the [stack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Call_stack). And `foo` is logged into the console.

Then `setTimeout(bar, 0)` is being called. `setTimeout(bar, 0)` being **asynchronous**, will be called later and pushed in the callback queue(this will be called later when the stack is empty). That's why we didn't see the console of `bar`.

After this `myPromise.then(resolve => console.log(resolve))` is called. And this is also an **asynchronous** call. So this will also be pushed to the callback queue.

Then `baz()` will be executed. And that's why we're seeing a log of `baz` after the `foo`.

Now remember, we've `console.log('before bar')` in the stack, so this will be logged first. And after this all the items in the callback queue will be called.

Three things are logged up to now:-
`foo`
`baz`
`before bar`

Now, the good thing about promises is they are being **prioritized** in the callback queue, over anything. So even `setTimeout` is being called before the our promise, if promise is **executed**, it will be **prioritized**.

That's the reason why `'should be right after baz, before bar'` is called before `bar`.