# What is the technical name for, "Unrelated asynchronous call stacks?" I want to say, "How do I wait until an unrelated ___ completes?"

Tags: javascript, terminology

Imagine code like this (this example errors, but it's only meant to clarify my question):

```
// In one code block...
const async1 = new Promise((resolve) => {
  addListenerThatResolvesWhenAsync2Completes(resolve);
});


// Potentially, in another code block. 
// Potentially, in a separate event loop iteration.
setTimeout(() => dispatchAsync2CompleteEvent(), delay); // this setTimeout "spawns" async2
```

1. `async1` is a Promise, `async2` is a `setTimeout`
2. Both are asynchronous.
3. They exist in separate chains; `async1` waits for `async2` to complete, but otherwise, they are unrelated.

If these were both promises, I wouldn't need to ask this question. I think people would understand what I meant if I said, "Promises running in parallel." But as far as I understand it, `setTimeout` - and therefore `async2` - doesn't create a Promise. Is there a term that means *"Promises and `setTimeout`'s running in parallel with unrelated call stacks?"*

If this were another programming language, I might be able to say "separate threads" or "separate processes", but neither of those are technically correct in the given example.

Comment: This sounds like a question for [english.se]...

Comment: I think they're just asynchronous operations.

Comment: @HereticMonkey That site is horrible for technical jargon. Whenever someone asks for something technical, I tell them to ask in the group specific to that profession.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I considered that but I thought this was the more appropriate place since I need a code example just to explain my question.

Comment: @Barmar That sounds close, but a Promise chain contains asynchronous operations too. How would I say something like, "*unrelated* asynchronous operations" without confusing people?

Comment: I don't think it's going to confuse people, the context will make it clear.

Comment: "Tasks", generically, although they go into different queues - see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/66387109/3001761. It might be better to ask a [meta] question (or hit chat) to get support writing the actual question you want to ask that you think will confuse people.

Comment: You could use the old standby "micro-" and "macro-tasks" a la [Difference between microtask and macrotask within an event loop context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25915634/215552)

Comment: @Barmar the context of the question body or the context of the question title? I'm looking for the latter (if it exists). FWIW, this q isn't just for my next SO question, I think the answer may be of use when communicating with other developers.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've never seen a Meta Stack Overflow question like this before, so I hadn't considered that, but apparently [Meta has a terminology tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/terminology). On the other hand, non-Meta SO has that tag too. I'm happy to move this to Meta, but why is it more appropriate there? To be honest, I would prefer to chat about this than post it on Meta, but I don't think I can create a chat unless there are lots more comments on this question :(

Comment: Fun fact: promises do not run in parallel, they're _just_ asynchronous (JS is single threaded, unless you're using workers, so there is _no parallelism_, only asynchronicity). Saying they run in parallel is "easy to say", while also saying the wrong thing. The code you're showing has an asynchronous dependency between a promise and (indirectly, because of that `addListenerThatResolvesWhenAsync2Completes`) a function triggered by a timer.

Comment: I mean in e.g. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript, not creating some room _just_ to decide what word you should use.

Comment: @jonrsharpe oh! I just went on a wild goose chase to find [how to get to chat.stackoverflow.com from SO.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/426951/61624). It's been so long since I've visited the chat landing page, I assumed it was removed and the feature was limited to comment threads now. I'm glad to see I was wrong. Thanks.

Comment: This question is kind of opinion based, since there is no correct answer. I might prefer "tasks" while someone else prefers "operations"; Both of us are "correct" and your question or whatever would be read and understood (or not).

Comment: @HereticMonkey I know I'm being obnoxiously pedantic here, but unless you've read all the async-related JS specifications, how do you know there is no correct answer? (Maybe you or someone *has* read them all, in which case, I'd agree with you and vote to close my question too.)

Comment: I have read a fair number of them, having been on this site for 11+ years. But nonetheless, this is a word choice question; it doesn't matter even if there is "the one true word" (that in the darkness binds them); one perfectly salient option is to ignore that and use some other phrase that means something to your audience that is less than 100% technically correct, but is more meaningful.

Comment: 1/2 I completely agree with your conclusion. When you say, `it doesn't matter even if there is "the one true word,"` I think you mean that in a pragmatic sense. But I was replying to you saying, ["This question is kind of opinion based, since there is no correct answer."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77355526/in-javascript-what-is-the-technical-name-for-unrelated-asynchronous-call-stac?noredirect=1#comment136372743_77355526) But having reread that, I may have misinterpreted what you meant:

Comment: 2/2 @HereticMonkey Are you saying there's no correct answer **because** there are multiple (in this case, 2)? If that's what you meant, I would accept an answer that includes both. Actually I'm prepared to accept bergi's answer, I just need a little clarification on one of his sentences.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans A perfectly accurate and perfectly reasonable way to think about it is that asynchronous tasks ***wait*** in parallel. It is the wait that happens in parallel because the thing you wait for executes in another program potentially in another computer half way around the world while your code does not execute anything. Code that orchastrate the wait and handles the resolved result run sequentially.

Comment: It doesn't matter that you'd accept the answer. Remember, questions and answers on Stack Overflow exist to help everyone with the same question, not just you, so whether you choose to accept an answer (or not) is completely up to you. And Stack Overflow is all about pragmatism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terms "threads" and "processes" refer to the specific operating system resources (or runtime, for threads managed by a virtual machine).

If you want to be less specific, just say "*asynchronous tasks*" or "*asynchronous operations*", which can run concurrently with each other. This means any sequence of code executions that are spawned in a (usually linear) chain, forming a unit of execution with a result.

Notice that promises do not "run", just like they are not "executed" - a promise represent an asynchronous result not a callable function.

Comment: Your answer is full of useful information. Thank you. I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by, `This means any sequence of code executions that are spawned in a (usually linear) chain`. Specifically, what do you mean by, "spawned in a usually linear chain?" Maybe you can expound on that. I think I'm looking for the term that means "they **aren't** spawned in a linear chain."

Comment: The "promises do not run" part of this answer is extremely important (to me). Promises represent things like bookmarks that are waiting for something *completely external to the runtime* to do something, and upon completion (or any other salient event) to notify the runtime that a thing has happened. There may be "running" happening somewhere, but it's not the Promise; it's just sitting there like a sticky note in the middle of a book.

Comment: @DanielKaplan I was trying to be really ambiguous there… Your first task has code that creates a promise, then waits for an event, then resolves the promise. Your second task has code that code that creates a timer, then the timer spawns another function call that runs an event dispatcher. Each of those sequences is linear I'd say.

Comment: @Pointy `Promises represent ... something completely external to the runtime to do something` Doesn't that depend on the implementation of the constructor and then/catch/finally callbacks? Looking at my example code, what part is completely external to "the runtime?"

Comment: @DanielKaplan file system operations, network requests to external services, even timer services: all those are brokered by the operating system beneath the runtime. If you know old-school UNIX programming (or modern Linux), a Promise represents something waiting for a `select()` call to trigger. Something is happening somewhere, but nothing about the existence of the Promise while waiting can really be described as "running".

Comment: @Pointy My point (no pun intended) is that a Promise doesn't **have** to wait on anything external to the runtime (correct me if I'm wrong). You said, `Promises represent ... something completely external to the runtime to do something` and I'm saying, "Often yes, but not necessarily." For example, what external runtime is `new Promise((resolve) => {resolve("hello world")}).then(console.log);` waiting for?

Comment: Well in that example clearly nothing, **except** for the next slot in the task queue. That's not really an active example of "waiting"; the resolved promise goes straight into the queue synchronously.

Comment: @DanielKaplan It is not the promise that "runs" or "waits for anything". It's a *task* that is waiting for the promise. It is also a task that does something and then resolves or rejects the promise. But the promise itself is just a notification (and caching, and sequencing) mechanism, it is not actively "doing" anything on its own but rather it is being used by some actors.