# setInterval at 1ms doesn't seem to actually be 1ms

Tags: javascript, timer, xmlhttprequest, setinterval

I'm trying to time how long a file takes to download using an HTTPRequest like so:

```
function getFile() {
    'use strict';
    var url = "data.bin";
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var timer_var = setInterval( theTimer, 1 );

    rawFile.open("GET", url, true);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(rawFile.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && rawFile.status === 200) {
            toLog(rawFile.responseText);
            window.clearInterval(timer_var);
            toLog("Milliseconds for download: " + time_taken);
        }
    };
    rawFile.send(null);
}

function theTimer() {
    'use strict';
    toLog(time_taken);
    time_taken++;
}
```

As you can see I have `setInterval` calling `theTimer` every one millisecond. All `thetimer()` does is increment a variable, which in theory should have a value in milliseconds of how long the interval was running.

When the file has been downloaded I output the data, clear the timer and display the time in ms. However, the value doesn't add up. I should be almost 2 seconds but only stands at around 250ms.

Why isn't the `setInterval` truly every 1ms?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is minimum millisecond value of setTimeout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647215/what-is-minimum-millisecond-value-of-settimeout)

Comment: If you want to know how long something took, compare timestamps. `setInterval` and family fire sometime after the given delay, when it gets a chance.

Comment: Hi Alex, timestamps! of course.

Comment: Good to know there is a delay using less than 10ms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval):

> **delay**
>
> The time, in milliseconds (thousandths of a second), the timer should
>    delay in between executions of the specified function or code. **If this
>    parameter is less than 10, a value of 10 is used.** Note that the actual
>    delay may be longer;

(Mozilla, but other browsers seem to use similar values)

There is also a reference to [the documentation of `setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified) mentioning reasons why "the actual delay may be longer".

In short:

- There is a minimum delay (already in the spec) for nested timeouts
- Inactive tabs may clamp timeouts to reduce load
- The page/browser/OS might be busy with other tasks

In modern browsers there seems to be [a way using `window.postMessage`](https://dbaron.org/log/20100309-faster-timeouts).

Comment: Thank for explaining the delay in setTimeout/setInterval. I think comparing timestamps is a good way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The delay for `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()` can be longer than the specified time. There are various reasons for this:

See [MDN WindowTimers.setTimeout(): Reasons for delays longer than specified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified) for more information.

Answer (score -2):

if you multiplied the result by 4 it will get the real number in ms .
i tried it just in chrome .