# How to determine es6-promise constructor execution order?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, jestjs, es6-promise

Consider the following code.

```
(async () => {
    const values = {}
    const orders = []
    let promise = 0
    promise = new Promise(async resolve => {
        values[1] = promise
        orders.push(1)
        resolve(1)
        values[2] = promise
        orders.push(2)
        await new Promise(async r => {
            values[3] = await promise
            orders.push(3)
            setTimeout(r, 100)
        })
        values[4] = await promise
        orders.push(4)
        promise = 2
        values[5] = promise
        orders.push(5)
    })
    values[6] = await promise
    orders.push(6)
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100)) // (*). try removing this line, result will change
    values[7] = await promise
    orders.push(7)
    console.log(values, orders)
})()
```

Console output:

```
{ '1': 0, '2': 0, '3': 0, '4': 1, '5': 2, '6': 1, '7': 1 }
[ 1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 5, 7 ]
```

My questions are:

1. Is there any statement in the above snippet which is undefined behavior? If no, I am confused of the ES6 promise after checking the result.
2. Why is `values[7]` `1`, not `2`? Update: with node v10.19.0, it is 1. With nodev14.0.0, node-v12.10.0 and browser, it is 2.

Update 2: repeating the evaluation with node v10.19.0, after 20 times of values[7] be 1, once it will be 2.

3. If I remove the (*) line, the result changes to below. Why are 4, 5 removed?

   { '1': 0, '2': 0, '3': 0, '6': 1, '7': 1 }
   [ 1, 2, 3, 6, 7 ]

If you have any rule of thumb for this kind of execution, please share. The more I write JS promise code, the more I get confused.

Check for more tests [here](https://github.com/tranvansang/promise-test/blob/master/promise.test.js).

Comment: First code smell.  `const values = {}` and `values[1] = ...`.  You are trying to treat an object like an array

Comment: "Now, without executing the code, can you give a correct answer to the final value of values?" Sounds like homework.

Comment: It is unclear why anyone would write code like that to begin with.

Comment: @epascarello I created this test myself lol

Comment: @Taplar it doesn't matter. numbers can be object keys.

Comment: I am aware of that, but my point remains.  If you are treating it like an array, you should use an array.  Unless you have a reason to not do so.

Comment: @epascarello actually, It happens in my real project, which made me to write this test code to confirm the language specs

Comment: @Taplar I did not treat `values` as an array. The indices present the code line number order, not runtime assignment order. That is why I use object by purpose, not by mistake.

Comment: WHAT do you not expect to work? My guess you are freaking out that promise resolve(2) is not updating for the code right after it.

Comment: @epascarello values[9] should be 6, but it is 5

Comment: [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)! Even if you're trying to write some scheduling puzzles.

Comment: "*If you have any rule of thumb for this kind*" - the rule is not to write convoluted asynchronous code that reassigns the same variable over and over :-)

Comment: @transang no it should be 5. because the `resolve(5)` updates your variable after you set it to 6.

Comment: I have to rethink the meaning of *obfuscated code*... And I thought that `(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]` resolving to `"l0l"` is considered obfuscated...

Comment: Most of these are well-defined and just run in order, but the `promise = 6` assignment and the `values[9] = await promise` form a classical race condition that depends on the execution speed, accuracy, and microtask semantics of `setTimeout`.

Comment: `promise` is a schizophrenic beast. Why?

Comment: @epascarello promise = 6 is placed **after** resolve(5). Actually, I do not think it (promise = 6) is getting called

Comment: @Bergi I want something more than the link you provided. Eventhough this is an antipattern, it has a well-defined behavior, what is the expected behavior?

Comment: @Bergi my question is about the rule of thumb is about the rule of determining the execution order, not rule of writing code.

Comment: @Bergi javascript is single-thread. There is no external factor (internet, IO, ...) here. I do not think there is a race condition.

Comment: regarding the second question. I posted another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61627447/what-is-the-random-factor-in-node-v10-event-loop)

Comment: @transang `setTimeout` *is* IO, and also its exact implementation is not specified but depends on the runtime environment (e.g. it works differently in node vs a browser). All I'm saying is that this part of the code is written in a manner that makes impossible to argue about deterministic execution order (two *independent* timeouts of similar length), which is a race condition.

Comment: @Bergi You are not correct. [this post](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) explains internal event loop of nodejs. setTimeout appends the callback to the timer loop with a very small (fixed) time value.

Comment: @transang And yet, it doesn't discuss subtle details in `setTimeout` such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61608974/1048572). And no, the event loops used by chrome and node are different!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's something you're confused about, try to distill it to *just* the case you are confused about, not all the other cases too, that said... my best guess to what I think you want to know:

1. The executor function (what you pass to `new Promise()`) gets called immediately, synchronously.
2. Async functions, when called, also get executed immediately. They will only pause when they hit the first `await`.
3. So if you use an async function that has no `await` in it, the
   entire async function will get executed synchronously, immediately.
4. However, even if you async function is "synchronous", it will not immediately return. Execution is synchronous, but resolving (handling `.then() listeners`) will be in the next tick).

Comment: does 2 hold if the waited value is not a promise. Consider 2 cases: it is a dynamic runtime-defined variable, and it is a constant non-promise variable

Comment: i have added test. `values[3]` is `0`, not `1`. Could you add more rules to cover this case?

Comment: @transang, no your question is too dense to try and interpret everything. Perhaps you can open a more specific question. You're basically asking to interpret the Promise and async/await specifications for you.

Comment: thanks. Can you explain why was `3` added to `orders`, before `6`? Does this contrast with your second rule?

Comment: I figured out the answer myself. because push(3) is scheduled (nextTick?) before push(6), it is executed first. The async function does stop at any await regardless the value of the awaited operand