# What is the random factor in node v10 event loop?

Tags: node.js, async-await, settimeout, race-condition, event-loop

My question is about nodejs [event loop](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/)

Consider this code

```
(async () => {
    let val = 1
    const promise = new Promise(async resolve => {
        resolve()
        await new Promise(async r => {
            setTimeout(r)
        })
        await promise
        val = 2
    })
    await promise
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve))
    console.log(val)
})()
```

With node 10.20.1 (latest version of node 10)

```
for ((i = 0; i < 30; i++)); do /opt/node-v10.20.1-linux-x64/bin/node race-timeout.js; done
```

With node 12.0.0 (the first version of node 12)

```
for ((i = 0; i < 30; i++)); do /opt/node-v12.0.0-linux-x64/bin/node race-timeout.js; done
```

The result of node 10

1
2
2
1
1
2
2
1
2
1
1
1
1
1
2
1
1
2
1
2
1
1
2
2
1
2
1
1
2
1

The result of node 12

2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2

So far, I have known that node is a single-thread language.
Everything is well-determined and executed in an exact order except when there is an intervention of the poll phase.

The above code does not include any undetermined factors (like IO, network, ...).
I expected that the result should be the same. However, with node v10, it is not.

What is the random factor in node v10?

Comment: Probably [this](https://v8.dev/blog/v8-release-72#async%2Fawait), which led to [this](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/pull/1250), though I'm not sure enough for an answer.

Comment: @Kaiido I guess that's the explanation why v12 is *different* from v10, but it doesn't explain why the output in v10 is not deterministic

Comment: Actually I was all wrong, async/await has nothing to do with (I had to inline the code into an MCVE to realize it...)

Answer (score 1):

It is all [explained here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/22257).

In a nutshell, before v.11 calling `Promise.resolve().then( fn1 ); setTimeout( fn2, 0 );` could lead to `fn2` being pushed to the queue of timers belonging to the current event loop iteration, and thus, `fn2` would fire before the event loop even entered the `nextTicks` queue (a.k.a "microtask-queue").

According to [one comment](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/22257#issuecomment-412731884) there, the discrepancy came from the fact "*the timers could get set on a different ms and thus expire 1ms apart*", thus pushing `fn2` to a next event loop iteration and leaving the `nextTicks` queue being processed in between.

In other words, v10 should most of the time output `1`, except when the main job was calling setTimeout in the next ms, for instance if the main job was called @ms 12.9, and that it took more than 0.1ms to get to the `setTimeout` call, then this `setTimeout`'s `0` value would actually match the next timer queue (@ms 13), and not the current one (@ms 12).

In [next versions](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/22842), `nextTicks` are ran after each `immediates` and `timers`, hence we are sure the Promise's callback will get executed right after the job that did execute it, just like in browsers.