# JS Promise's inconsistent execution order between nodejs versions

Tags: node.js, async-await, es6-promise

I am reading the article about nodejs promise [here](https://v8.dev/blog/fast-async).

Then I try running the following sample code (from the article)

```
const p = Promise.resolve();

(async () => {
  await p; console.log('after:await');
})();

p.then(() => console.log('tick:a'))
 .then(() => console.log('tick:b'));
```

The results are inconsistent between node versions. With node v10 staying out of all other versions.

I am using a mac.

```
v8.17.0
after:await
tick:a
tick:b

v10.20.1
tick:a
tick:b
after:await

v12.17.0
after:await
tick:a
tick:b

v14.3.0
after:await
tick:a
tick:b
```

The article says that v10 introduces a breaking change to correct the execution order and the behavior of v8 is a bug. However, when I tested with v12 and v14, they give the same result as v8.

Could anyone explain to me why this happens?

[image]

Comment: @jfriend00 the article is about breaking change in node v10. It says that nodev10 implements the correct specs and behavior of v8 is a bug. However, when I tested with v12, v14, they give same result as v8. I should have included this info in my question

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61627447/what-is-the-random-factor-in-node-v10-event-loop) is another question (from me). I have no idea about this but I guest there maybe a relation between them

Comment: Good luck with these intellectual curiosity problems.  I will follow the answers out of curiosity, but I prefer to write my code so if a specific ordering between promise chains is required, then the code declaratively forces that ordering in the way it is written without relying on this level of engine implementation detail.

Comment: Been trying to recreate the differing behavior without using `async` / `await` but everything I've written seems to produce the behavior of Node 8/12/14, even in Node 10. I'm inclined to say that Node 8 actually performs the correct behavior as per the current specification. To me, it seems like that article is saying there was a modification to the procedure in the specification between versions 10 and 12, so 8 was wrong in the old spec, 10 was right in the old spec, and 12 and 14 are right in the new spec.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to [this change in the specs](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/pull/1250) which now allows shortcircuiting `await promiseInstance` to not wrap `promiseInstance` into a new *Promise* internally and hence saving two ticks (one for waiting for `promiseInstance` and one to wake up the *async* function).

[Here is a detailed article](https://v8.dev/blog/fast-async#await-under-the-hood) from the authors of the specs' patch, which also occur to be v8 devs. In there, they explain how that behavior was actually already in nodejs v.8 but was against the specs by then, i.e a bug, that they fixed in v.10, before this patch makes it the official way of doing, and it gets implemented in v8 engine directly.

So if you wish the inlined version that should have happened before this patch is

```
const p = Promise.resolve();

new Promise((res) => p.then(res)) // wait for p to resolve
  .then((res) => Promise.resolve(res)) // wake up the function
  .then((res) => console.log('after:await'));

p.then(() => console.log('tick:a'))
 .then(() => console.log('tick:b'));
```

while the patch makes it

```
const p = Promise.resolve();

p.then(() => console.log('after:await'));

p.then(() => console.log('tick:a'))
 .then(() => console.log('tick:b'));
```