# DOM event firing order vs setTimeout

Tags: javascript, dom, events, cross-browser, settimeout

Let's say I have a `<div>`.

When `onMouseUp` fires, I do `setTimeout(..., 0)`.

Is the `onClick` event guaranteed to fire before the timeout?

Comment: click event will occur some ms after the mousedown - at the time of mousedown, there's no click event on the stack (as you haven't *moused-up*) so your code will always run first.  @Ivar 's [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1f7g5j4p/) also confirms this.

Comment: @freedomn-m I actually got mixed up smh, and meant the mouse up event! The timeout does fire after for me but I'm wondering if this is guaranteed according to the spec

Comment: Not sure about `<button onclick=` as never use inline handlers - I seem to recall that inline handlers run last (or was it first) - but that would compare `onclick=` with `$("btn").click(..`

Comment: A quick [update](https://jsfiddle.net/swgLmap0/) the to the above fiddle shows that mouseup and click events are fired at the same time (assuming mouseup is within the time frame for a click so you do get a click).  Thus, as per first (now deleted comment), there is a already a click event on the "stack" so your timeout code gets added after this and runs after the click event.  You could always change to `setTimeout(..., 5)` to be sure as the user won't notice the difference.

Comment: Note: there's a *minimum* period for setTimeout (SO answer somewhere) - anything below 4 is counted as 4.  **edit** here's the question: [minimum value of stettimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9647221/2181514) (though later (time-wise) comments appear to indicate this has been removed)